# Yesod i18n, defaultLayout, and ihamlet

Tags: haskell, internationalization, yesod

I am trying to convert the tutorial code in Chapter 2 of the forthcoming "Play for Scala" book from Scala to Haskell (using Yesod). I am getting an error trying to "internationalize" my `defaultLayout`. I am (purposely) not using a scaffolded Yesod site because I am trying to understand the internals. Here is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances
           , MultiParamTypeClasses
           , OverloadedStrings
           , QuasiQuotes
           , TemplateHaskell
           , TypeFamilies #-}

module Main where

import Text.Hamlet (ihamlet)
import Yesod
import Yesod.Static

staticFiles "static"

data PlayTutorial = PlayTutorial
  { getStatic :: Static
  }

mkMessage "PlayTutorial" "messages" "en"

mkYesod "PlayTutorial" [parseRoutes|
  / RootR GET
  /static StaticR Static getStatic
|]

instance Yesod PlayTutorial where
  defaultLayout contents = do
    PageContent title headTags bodyTags <- widgetToPageContent $ do
      addStylesheet $ StaticR stylesheets_bootstrap_css
      addStylesheet $ StaticR stylesheets_main_css
      contents

    ihamletToRepHtml [ihamlet|
      $doctype 5

      <html>
        <head>
          <title>#{title}
          ^{headTags}
        <body>
          <div ."screenshot">
            <div ."navbar navbar-fixed-top">
              <div ."container">
                <a ."brand" href=@{RootR}>
                  _{MsgApplicationName}
            <div ."container">
              ^{bodyTags}
    |]

getRootR :: Handler RepHtml
getRootR = defaultLayout [whamlet|Hello, World!|]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  static@(Static settings) <- static "static"
  warp 8080 $ PlayTutorial static
```

The error I get trying to build or run it with `runhaskell` is

```
src/Main.hs:34:31:
    Couldn't match type `Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM ()'
                  with `[(Data.Text.Internal.Text, Data.Text.Internal.Text)]
                        -> Data.Text.Internal.Text'
    Expected type: Text.Hamlet.Render (Route PlayTutorial)
      Actual type: Text.Hamlet.Translate (Route PlayTutorial)
    In the first argument of `headTags', namely `_mrender_a7j2'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: headTags _mrender_a7j2 _urender_a7j1
    In the expression:
      do { id
             ((Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . Data.Text.pack)
                "<!DOCTYPE html>\
                \<html><head><title>");
           id (toHtml title);
           id
             ((Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . Data.Text.pack) "</title>");
           headTags _mrender_a7j2 _urender_a7j1;
           .... }
```

The error occurs on the `ihamlet` code.

I believe that `headTags` is a `HtmlUrl`. I also think I need to convert that to a `HtmlUrlI18n`, but can't figure out how.

Can I do the same thing (define `defaultLayout`) as a widget (using `whamlet`) then convert it to a `PageContent` using `widgetToPageContent`, then to a `RepHtml` (not sure how), instead of using `ihamlet`? Will that solve the i18n problem?

I have tried Googling for a couple of hours but cannot find any extensive examples that create a new `defaultLayout` with i18n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a brief discussion with Michael Snoyman (the originator and lead developer of the Yesod Framework) on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/yesodweb/7YiJvsNZxBw), I believe I now understand the problem, and more importantly, the solution.

`headTags` has

```
type HtmlUrl url = Render url -> Html
```

and the `^{}` interpolation in `ihamlet` expects

```
type HtmlUrlI18n msg url = Translate msg -> Render url -> Html
```

so we have to convert from one to the other.

The function `const` in the Prelude is defined as

```
const :: a -> b -> a
const x _ =  x
```

so if we embed `const headTags` in the `^{}` interpolation, it works.

The expression `const headTags` is a *currying* from a function that expects two arguments to one that expects a single argument. The second argument is then ignored. The interpolation calls that single-argument function and passes in a `Translate msg`, which is ignored, leaving a function of type `Render url -> Html`, exactly what we passed in with `headTags`.

The same logic applies to `bodyTags`.

Thanks, Michael.